# Call another method if any selected property value changed - C#

Tags: c#

I have `customer` class with property. Here is my sample code

```
public class Customer {
public string Name {
    get;
    set;
}
public string Deparment {
    get;
    set;
}
public string AccountNo {
    get;
    set;
}

public void UpdateUserProfile(int customerId, string name, string department, string accountNo) {
    bool isNeedUpdateAccount = false;

    var customer = _context.Customers.First(c = >c.Id == customerId);

    customer.Name = name;

    if (department != customer.Deparment) {
        customer.Department = department;

        isNeedUpdateAccount = true;
    }

    if (accountNo != customer.AccountNo) {
        customer.AccountNo = accountNo;

        isNeedUpdateAccount = true;
    }

    _context.SaveChanges();

    //Check is need to update account

    if (isNeedUpdateAccount) {
        UpdateAccount(customer);
    }
}

public void UpdateAccount(Customer model) {
    // Do other business logic
}
```

As you see here, I need to check `department` and `accountNo` value. If value is changed then I will call another method.

Is OK if only got a `few property` need to check. But let say if I have more than 5 so make my code to long.

Any method can make it more simple?

If the question is not clear please let me know

Comment: Is it an option that your class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: Your code does not compile as is.

Comment: why don't you check on department and accountNo setter. like you can use as following.   int accountNo;
        public int AccountNo
        {
            get { return accountNo; }
            set
            {
                if (value != accountNo)
                {
                    //do something
                }
                accountNo = value;
            }
        }

Comment: Sometimes it' useful to just serialize the two objects and check if the result differs. Could prefer binary serialization, but string-based one like XAML or JSON would also do

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your case, is that you are updating the customer in `UpdateUserProfile` under each `if` statement. To do it in a nicer way, you need to get ride of that (move to another part). and then, you can use reflection to compare both objects, but they will be checked entirely. 
But to do that you need to send to `UpdateUserProfile` a `Customer`

```
public void UpdateUserProfile(Customer newCustomer) {

    var customer = _context.Customers.First(c = >c.Id == customerId);

    var isNeedUpdateAccount = IsDifferent(customer, newCustomer)

    if(isNeedUpdateAccount){
    //TODO: Update the current Customer
     _context.SaveChanges();
    }


    if (isNeedUpdateAccount) {
        UpdateAccount(customer);
    }
}

public bool IsDifferent(Customer c1, Customer c2)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in c1.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        object value1 = property.GetValue(c1, null);
        object value2 = property.GetValue(c2, null);
        if (!value1.Equals(value2))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

in addition you can modify the method `IsDifferent` to return to you which properties are changed if you return a list of `PropertyInfo` instead of a bool.

If for any reason you don't want to compare the entire object, I reccomend you to write an extension method which compares the few properties you need.